# How can I modify specific line of code using cmd

Tags: .net, batch-file

I am using **`cmd`** scripts to shift resources from one location to other. Its working fine.

Now I have got requirement to make changes in my code where I have to comment one line of code and uncomment another line. Ex. code

```
public class SISConst
{
    //public const string SIS_APIKey = "AIzaSyrGUAXMezp86waQ";
    //public const string KPS_APIKEy = "AAAAqoT4xTw:APA91bHr3OS";
    //public const string Chanllengers_APIKey = "AIzaSyEfzyaCu8X22FmCXjOE";
    //public const string Trividyaa_APIKey = "AIzaSMFP4B3ddDXKLFrZxoKI";
    //public const string Global_APIKey = "AIzaSyCsZIgMKdxrDKtfVTI";
    //public const string Tulip_APIKey = "AIzaSyA1tP5iw7jTxW6JaliL-9Rc";
    //public const string Lmg_APIKey = "AIzaSyDYLKojBk-vVVDiq2DSH0";
    public const string RisingSun_APIKey = "AIzaSyAFh-wkAFYrXJHnrww"; 
}
```

**Edit:** I am shifting resources based on param given in `clientname.txt` file. In this text file just giving client folder like(From above code)  SIS, KPS, Global, Tulip. But here case is different I have only file called `SISConst`. The client param should be the name in variable before `_`. Say  `SIS_APIKey` is `SIS`, `KPS_APIKey` is `KPS` so on. Now in client file I would give these names `KPS`, `SIS` etc. I don't see other clue.

As of now I am using this code to move resources

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (1.ClientName.txt) DO ( 

XCOPY "..\AppIcons\%%A\drawable-hdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-hdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
```

How can I write query to making code modification, is it possible at all?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe a batch script is not a best choice for such work. Consider Powershell or VBScript.

Comment: Please note that this site is for members to help you fix a specific issue with your code. It is not a site where you post code which does not in any way attempt a task, and wait for somebody to write it for you. Please use the command prompt help, the web, and/or books to learn how to do it and then attempt the task yourself. If the code then fails to work as written and intended, you can edit your question to make it on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So first off, batch is not the best tool for this job. If the file content changes in any way (additional/less spaces, etc) it will affect the output. So this is a complete hack.

**Note**, you need to replace the name of your actual file, containing public classes where I have `FILENAMEHERE`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "inputfile=D:\Arvind.ch\SIS\SIS_Product\SIS-Global-Dev\edTheSIS\RisingSun\MainActivity.cs"
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (1.ClientName.txt) do (
    set "client=%%A"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\drawable-hdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-hdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H          >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\drawable-mdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-mdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H          >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\drawable-xhdpi\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable-xhdpi\" /E /F /R /Y /H        >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\GoogleJsonFile\*" "..\RisingSun\" /E /F /R /Y /H     >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\LoginPageImage\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable\" /E /F /R /Y /H      >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\MenifestFile\*" "..\RisingSun\Properties\" /E /F /R /Y /H            >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\SplashScreenImage\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\drawable\" /E /F /R /Y /H      >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"
    xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\StringFile\*" "..\RisingSun\Resources\values\" /E /F /R /Y /H      >> "..\AppIcons\%%A\copy.log"

   )
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| findstr "!client!"') do set "finder=%%i"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputfile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%inputfile%"') do (
              set "str=%%a"
              set "str=!str:*]=!"
              set "str=!str:            pushInfo.ServerkeyPush=         //pushInfo.ServerkeyPush!"
              if "!str!"=="!finder!" set "str=!str://pushInfo.ServerkeyPush=pushInfo.ServerkeyPush!"
             >>%inputfile% echo(!str!
)
```

Comment: is `MainActivity.cs` in the same directory as the batch file? if not, put full path to it. i.e `set "inputfile=D:\Some dir\MainActivity.cs`

Comment: and what happened to the secondlast line? it says `>>%in` it should be `>>%inputfile% echo(!str!`\

Comment: ok, that file is alot different than in the original question.

Comment: give me a second to check please.

Comment: Please copy everything now _"exactly"_ as is.. if you still get the error of _cannot find path_ `rem` each line of your xcopy and see which one it is... for instance `xcopy "..\AppIcons\%%A\MenifestFile\*"` is that right? should it not be `ManifestFile` ?

Comment: Now not getting that error. The code is modifying too. But file getting changed on many places. one line of code adding every after 10 lines. `!=` condition getting changed to `==` :).  Check this https://ibb.co/1f5xFr4

Comment: ok, but again, I asked earlier how many lines in the file, you said only those mentioned, so now it is a much bigger file and alot more to cater for. I never had the full content of the file.

Comment: Oh! I thought you are asking about those specific strings. I appreciate your help. Let me try to have separate file for this as you said. If anything required I would ask another question instead of elongating it. Thank you so much.